# How to create a document in jtextpane?

Tags: styles, jtextpane

I'm sorry, maybe there is such a question.
I'm a beginner.
I want to make jtextpane with this form, as shown below.
I understand that the Style do the first part of the document.
I do not understand how to insert the table after the text.
Please help me.
Very grateful.
[document in jtextpane](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8c8DW.jpg)

Comment: http://java-sl.com/JEditorPaneTables.html

Answer (score 0):

You need an [HTMLDocument](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/html/HTMLDocument.html%20%22HTMLDocument). Set an [HTMLEditorKit](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/html/HTMLEditorKit.html%20HTMLEditorKit) to your text pane. Then, use [insertHTML](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/html/HTMLEditorKit.html#insertHTML%28javax.swing.text.html.HTMLDocument,%20int,%20java.lang.String,%20int,%20int,%20javax.swing.text.html.HTML.Tag%29%20insertHTML) to insert your table.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I found examples of HTMLDocument. I think this is the right solution. Once again, thank you very much !!!